# Confusion about the mac and osx tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I am confused about the `[mac]` (4589) and `[osx]` (4980) tags.

I think that most developers talk about Mac OS X and start to write **mac** as tag, but no **mac-os-x** is suggested so they simply tag the question with `[mac]` but they meant `[osx]`.

I would like to have a `[mac-os-x]` tag instead of both `[mac]` and `[osx]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag wikis *on Super User* claim (emphasis mine):

- [**`[mac]`**](https://superuser.com/tags/mac/info) — Any and all questions that relate to **the actual hardware** of Macintosh, a brand of computers created and sold by Apple Inc.. Includes the iMac, Mac mini, Mac Pro, MacBook Pro, MacBook Air, and MacBook. Not to be confused with MAC address. [...] Questions about Mac OS X should be tagged [`[osx]`](https://superuser.com/tags/osx/info). [...]
- [**`[osx]`**](https://superuser.com/tags/osx/info) — Software related questions on **the Mac OS X, an operating system** created and sold by Apple Inc. [...]

I don't know if the same is expected on Stack Overflow though. A tag wiki surely would help take away *some* of the confusion.

Comment: That sounds good for SU. But I don't see a need for a `[mac]` tag on SO since it's all about software. And as I wrote in the question, I think that many people tag questions with **mac** because there is no **mac-os-x** suggested. So I think it would be best to only have a `[mac-os-x]` tag on StackOverflow.